# How to optimize this LINQ to EF/Sql query (many to many to many relationship)?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I am implementing a permission system, where Users are in Roles and this roles then have permissons and I am thinking of the fastest way to query them:

[image]

At the moment I have following LINQ query:

```
var grant = db.Permissions.Any(p => p.Group == group && p.PermissionKey == permission
&& !p.Roles.Any(r => !r.IsAllowed && r.Role.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == user.Identity.Name)) 
&& p.Roles.Any(r => r.IsAllowed && r.Role.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == user.Identity.Name)));

return grant;
```

This takes about 1-2ms after EF has the entities cached (15-20ms the first time). This is not very slow, but as this can be queried a lot (e.g. the menu system checks for every item if the user is allowed to see that item) **I am asking if there is something faster possible?**

The only thing I can think of at the moment is to create a User<->Permission cache to get rid of the query at all after the first call, but caching is always a last resort for me (especially as you nned to think of clearing it if permissions change aso.).

**Update:** Using `Any` as suggested by Marcin, but is not faster...

**Update 2:** I moved the `IsAllowed` to the mapping table and adapted the query to use only one...

Comment: Can't you do a query for multiple items, and cache the results for a fairly short time, say 30 seconds? That way you do get fairly accurate results, and the advantage of a single query.

Comment: @Maarten: What do you mean by "query for multiple items"? Was that meant for my "menu example"?

Comment: @chrfin Checking for multiple (all) the required permissions at the same time - with a database-centered join - would reduce the queries. But I only use LINQ2SQL so I don't know how EF caching fits in ..

Comment: how many entries have your tables? how many will they have in a few month? I would definitly go for some cache, if those queries are run very often. even a cache latch time of 1 second will remarkably add performance. And what about a database that is not running on the same machine? maybe a cartesian product will help you here. have you tried `join`?

Comment: AND: You are running two times almost the same query, just having `IsAllowed` altered: What about querying the value of `IsAllowed`?

Comment: @MareInfinitus: I will definitly use caching in the end, but first I would like to improve the query itself as good as possible. 
Combining the two queries was also my idea, but I could not think of one which does the same as thes two (IsAllowed in at least one Role, but no Role with !IsAllowed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change every `Count() > 0` statement into `Any` method call, e.g.:

```
r => r.Users
      .Count(u => u.UserName == user.Identity.Name) > 0
```

should be replaced with:

```
r => r.Users
      .Any(u => u.UserName == user.Identity.Name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip - looks alot better, but does not affect the performance (I guess EF creates the same query out of it).

Comment: +1 the intent of the code is much more readable.  Was surprised that the performance was the same.  Maybe EF has an optimizer that interprets both of those LINQ to EF queries in the same manner?

Comment: Regardless of if EF optimizes `Count() > 0` to `Any()`, I'd imagine the SQL Query Planner treats both the same (i.e. `COUNT(x) > 0`), if it goes through that way ..

Comment: I will accept your solution as it helped me the most. For now I stick with this and a 1s cache...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating an indexed view in the database instead?

```
CREATE VIEW mySchema.UserRolePermission
WITH SCHEMABINDING
/* your SELECT goes here */
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX MyIndexName
ON mySchema.UserRolePermission (UserName, PermissionKey);
GO
```

Then your LINQ2SQL query becomes a straight select from this view instead. It may be faster because SQL server will create an index on the UserName and PermissionKey fields that you are using to do your search. Since this is a permission system I am assuming that you are not inserting into these tables that often (the indexed view may slow inserting down a little) but that you are reading from it more often.

The second time you fire this query off may also not be faster because of EF caching, but instead may be because of SQL server caching. Not sure, but may be worth trying it out.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the DB is not the "problem" as EF caches all the entities anyway, so its more "how to better query the object model"...